# comment in comment for blog post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the Mean Stack and trying to get a comment in comment feature to work for a blog post.

Where i'm getting stuck is trying to get from angular to mongo to update a comment for a given blog and a comment for a comment. I basically don't know how to get angular/express/mongoose to use the a subdocument id or nested subdocument id to update the parent blog or comment.

What I have managed to do so far is:

Create my schema -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var childSchema = new Schema;
childSchema.add({ 
firstName: 'string', 
lastName: 'string', 
comment: 'string', 
children: [childSchema] 
});

var parentSchema = new Schema({
firstName: 'string',
lastName: 'string',
blog: 'string',
children: [childSchema]
});

var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
```

Load Mongo with some data -

```
{
"firstName": "bobby",
"lastName": "edwards",
"blog": "this is blog 6",
"children": [
                {
            "firstName": "cat",
            "lastName": "edwards",
            "comment": "this is blog 6.1",
            "children": [  
                            {
                        "firstName": "dave",
                        "lastName": "edwards",
                        "comment": "this is blog 6.2",
                        "children": []
                         }]
            }]
}
```

Get all blogs with nested comments from mongo and display correctly in angular - each blog or comment has a form attached

Return a single parent blog -

Create a parent blog -

**UPDATED**

I have managed to get one level down but for this i had to send the comment id as a param, modify the express route and pass the results of findbyid to results.comment.id({_id: req.params.comment_id}).

Node App

```
  app.get('/parent/:post_id/:comment_id', postsController.single);
```

Node Controller

```
  module.exports.single = function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.post_id);
  Parent.findById({ _id: req.params.post_id }, function (err, results) {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
      }
  var id = results.children.id({ _id: req.params.comment_id }); //function (err, commentresults) {

     console.log('triggered 2');
     console.log(id);
     res.json([id]);
  });
};
```

That being said this was for learning/testing and can't see how this would work if i needed to create/return/update a comment 10 levels down.

Comment: So what is the problem? The schema is defined correctly to consider the same children schema conditions on nested levels.

Comment: I don't understand how I can iterate through nested comments given that the nesting could be 2 levels or 50 levels deep. What would the node controller/service look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this from a different perspective, I'd just have two optional fields, `topLevelCommentId` and `commentOwnerId`, in your schema.

Anytime you insert a comment, then, as long as you appropriately set the topLevelCommentId as the top level parent, and commentOwnerId as the immediate parent, you should have no problem getting your comments nested appropriately.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for getting back to me. I'm getting stuck on how to iterate through a list of nested comments where comments could be 2 or 10 levels deep. When I first load the blog page I get everything and get Angular ng-repeat post in posts, ng-repeat comment in post.comments with ng-include to display the blogs and nested comments within comments. All good. So given I have the blog id at level 1 and comment id which could be the comment at level 10 how do I iterate from the node controller/service?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've done angular, but I think the way you go about it is creating a template that nests itself, looking for all comments that belong to it via `commentOwnerId`.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I'm good on the Angular part I have that working. On the node/express/mongoose I'm struggling with. How do I return a comment, let's say 10 subdocuments deep without having to send 10 parent ids?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback. I think I need to gain a better understanding of what is possible in MongoDB. Therefore I have decided to sit a couple of MongoDB University course. One on the Development Side and one on the Operation Side.